# Django 1.8.5 migrations not working

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a Django 1.8.5 app with a MySQL database, with two other developers.

We've made changes to models.py, and now I'm trying to run migrations. When I run `python manage.py makemigrations` it returns "No changes detected." When I run `python manage.py migrate` it returns:

```
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: webstack_django_sorting, staticfiles, 
debug_toolbar, messages, linaro_django_pagination, humanize, django_tables2
  Apply all migrations: admin, schools, contenttypes, auth, sessions
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
 Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

I've tried deleting migration files/resetting migrations, as suggested in other posts, and nothing changed when I ran the `makemigrations` or `migrate` commands after deleting/resetting.

I've also tried `python manage.py makemigrations app_name` but get the same results.

The two other developers on my team have run the migrate commands successfully. When they run `python manage.py makemigrations` they're then prompted to rename old fields to match new fields in both models in our app. I'm not prompted with this; as I mentioned above, I'm told no changes are detected.

I'm working from the same code they are; pulled it from GitHub this morning, and we made sure what I'm working with is the most recent version. It is.

When I view the app on my local server, nothing appears where it should, indicating that the database is empty.

Any ideas of what else to try?

Comment: Why aren't the migrations themselves in the code you've pulled from GitHub? They should be. Individual developers shouldn't be making migrations for code that is already committed.

Comment: Did you make the changes to the model? This usually happens when someone else already committed a migration which django thinks it has been already migrated. If you reset your migrations files by deleting them then you need to also delete the migration records from the database in the "django_migrations" table.

Answer (score 0):

A similar thing happened to me in django 1.11 and it was because when I removed the migration files and reset the migrations table in the database I accidentally removed the init file in the migrations folder.

You should have something similar to this so that django can create the new migration files:

```
. . .
├── my_app
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
├── manage.py
. . .
```

Hope it helps!